# Camera stopped working after OSB and KDELive installed

Tags: 18.04, camera

My camera has stopped working after I installed OBS and used KDELive and now the camera is showing blank.
I am including some of the settings but I can't see any problem.

[image]

I have also uninstalled OBS and KDELive but the problem persists

Edit:
Installation of OBS was like that:

```
 1900  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
 1901  sudo apt install obs-studio
       sudo apt remove obs-studio
```

Also I didn't install KDELive. I am running it from the `kdenlive-20.12.2-x86_64.appimage` file

Edit2:
I was on ubuntu 18.04 and now I have upgraded to 20.04 but I still have this problem

Comment: How did you install it and how did you remove it?

Comment: I have added my answer to your reply

Comment: You did not say the command you used to uninstall it.

Comment: I have added the remove command as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (as it is said in many answers) that the camera's lense was switched off.
Since it's a relatively new laptop that I got from my office I was unaware of this functionality.

It's a Lenovo thinkpad L490 that has a physical switch that shuts down the camera lense.
So here is the camera switched off
[image: Lense switched off]
And here is how it looks when it is switched one and recording

[image]